# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute ( on a separate collection )

Tags: c#, collections

So I have been struggling with this one, i cannot logically see why this particular error is being thrown as i am modifiying a different collection thats not part of the enumeration.

below is my code

```
var ResultsDict = cache["ResultsDictionary"] as Dictionary<string, ContentModel>;

var Resultscopy = ResultsDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
var ResultsList = new List<ContentModel>();

foreach (var Result in ResultsDict.ToList())
{
    foreach (var link in Result.Value.LinksOnNode)
    {
        if (ResultsDict.ContainsKey(link))
        {
            Resultscopy[Result.Key].LinksOnNode.Remove(link);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown when trying to remove 'link' in the if statement. But i cant see why. ResultsCopy should be a completely separate collection from the ResultsDict collection that the foreach loop is enumerating.

Can someone please explain to me what i have missed? There seems to be something fundamental here that i am not quite understanding.

I have gone through several posts and tried their solutions but nothing seems to work. I have tried everything i can think of to create a copy of the ResultsDict without creating a reference but i still keep getting this error.

Comment: Long story short: you cannot modify a collection that is used in a `foreach` loop. Use a `for` instead.

Comment: @Alex Read the code, he isn't looping over the same collection he's altering

Comment: but the collection im trying to modify is outside the foreach loop? its not the collection that i am looping through

Comment: You're looping over LinksOnNode and try to remove link from it. You have two separate collections but each of them points to the same LinksOnNode collection.

Comment: ah... that sounds pretty logical

Comment: Note that LINQ `.ToList()` or `.ToDictionary()` methods create a copy of collection and nested collections are not copied, instead objects in them have same referenes. So if A and B are collections that have nested collection X and we type `var C = A.ToList()`. C will have identical list X as A or B (not copy but the same list) and if we try to modify that list in A  running a foreach in C.X  - there will be an exception!

Comment: Thank you, the issue has been solved now, it didn't even occur to me that nested collections would not be copied and still reference themselves in a new collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are modifying with:

```
Resultscopy[Result.Key].LinksOnNode.Remove(link);
```

But also iterating a "LinksOnNode" collection:

```
foreach (var link in Result.Value.LinksOnNode)
```

I think that one of the collections "LinksOnNode" is also being iterated (remember these will be the same).

Try changing your foreach to this:

```
foreach (var link in Result.Value.LinksOnNode.ToArray())
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, though rather than ToArray i used ToList(). 
i will accept the answer when i am allowed to. 

It never occurred to me that any nested collections would still be referencing themselves in a copied collection

Comment: Of course ... it's not deep copying ... just like ToArray() is just creating a new *collection*, but the underlying objects are the same ...